Proving that the sum of two angles equals to 180°
In the isosceles ΔABC AC = CB, M and N are the midpoints of AC and AB, respectively, D is an arbitrary point on the side AC. The circumcircle of ΔMND intersects BD for the second time at K, P is the midpoint of MK. Let NP intersect BD at Q and MK intersect the circumcircle of ΔNQB at X and Y. Prove that ∠AXC + ∠AYC = 180°.
This question was on the trial olympiad that was held by my school, and I couldn't solve it.
Here is the diagram:

Well, I've tried to do some angle chasing, but it seems too hard to get to those angles. I've also tried to get to the ratios of some segments (for example, if we'll consider point T as the second intersection of (MND) and AB, then $AM * AD = AN * AT$ and $BK * BD = BN * BT$, this gives us that $\frac{AM * AD}{BK * BD} = \frac{AT}{BT}$, or $\frac{AM * AD * BT}{BK * BD * AT} = 1$, and this could probably be used in the Menelaus's or Ceva's theorems, but I don't see how.)
On the GeoGebra plot I've noticed that the quadrilateral ADQN is cyclic. That's all my observations by now.

Let $E$ be the intersection point other than $D$ of the circumcircles of $\triangle DAB$ and $\triangle DMK$. Then $E$ is the spiral similarity center which sends segment $KB$ to $MA$, and since $P$ is the midpoint of $KM$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $AB$, it also sends $KB$ to $PN$. Consequently, $\triangle ENP \sim \triangle EBK$, so
$$\angle ENQ = \angle ENP = \angle EBK = \angle EBQ,$$
and hence $E$ lies on the circumcircle of $\triangle NQB$. We then have $\angle EBN = \angle EBA = 180^\circ - \angle EDM = \angle ENM$, so $NM$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle NQB$.
Now the rest is straightforward. By the tangency, we see that $MN^2 = MX \cdot MY$. Now let $X'$ be the reflection of $X$ over $M$. Then
$$ MA \cdot MC = MA^2 = MN^2 = MX \cdot MY = MX' \cdot MY, $$
and since $X'$ and $Y$ lie on different sides of $AC$ it follows that $AX'CY$ is cyclic. Therefore, $\angle AXC = \angle AX'C = 180^\circ - \angle AYC$.
Remark 1. From the tangency above, it's also easy to show that $ADQN$ is cyclic but this is not necessary for our solution.
Remark 2. Olympiad geometry problems like this are better posted to https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6_high_school_olympiads since you are more likely to get an answer there.

That's great and also very beautiful, thank you. How did you know that you need to mark a point E? I mean, how is it possible to think of that?

@Meison My main reason for adding $E$ is to get rid of the point $Q$ since it is really bad. I’ve seen from other problems that the line connecting two midpoints can be handled by a spiral similarity center sending one segment to another so I decided to try adding it. But I was not expecting it to solve the problem immediately! Hope that helps~
